# No consigo sacar el valor de una función me sale UNDEFINED!

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongoose

Soy novato en node.js y javascript y tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo una función en javascript en la cuál quiero primero acceder a un elemento dentro de un objeto que está dentro de un array. En el caso de que el valor de este sea igual al parametro. Quiero devolver el valor de otro elemento dentro del siguiente objeto.

Cuando hago console.log(final) dentro del for loop me devuelve el resultado que quiero. Pero cuándo asigno la función a una variable y hago el console.log de su resultado fuera me da undefined!!

Porfabor ayuda y Muchas gracias!!

Dejo el codigo debajo...

```js
router.get("/cursos/:id/enrolled/:tema/:page", function(req,res){
 Cursos.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundCourse){
  if(err){
   res.redirect("/cursos");
  } else {
   var page = req.params.page;
   var tema = req.params.tema;
   var found= foundCourse.content;
   
  var siguiente = found.forEach(function(element){
      for (var i = 0; i < element.index.length; i++){
        if(element.index[i].ref == tema){
         var next = i + 1;
         var final = element.index[next].ref;
         
        }  
       }
      return final;
      })
  console.log(siguiente) //returns undefined 

  res.render("cursos/" + tema + page, {curso: foundCourse, page: page, tema: tema});
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que contiene  `found`? El atributo `content` es un array de elementos, y cada elemento tiene un atributo `index` que es un array de temas? Pareciera ser más eficiente usar Array.filter que el bucle que estás haciendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que puedo ver a simple vista tu variable:

> var final

La estas declarando dentro del contexto de tu bloque for/if, por lo que en unos ciclos estara definida y en otros estara UNDEFINED.

Intenta el siguiente codigo y dime que tal te va.

Saludos

```
router.get("/cursos/:id/enrolled/:tema/:page", function(req,res){
Cursos.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundCourse){
    if(err){
        res.redirect("/cursos");
    } else {
        var page = req.params.page;
        var tema = req.params.tema;
        var found= foundCourse.content;
        var final="";

    var siguiente = found.forEach(function(element){
                    for (var i = 0; i < element.index.length; i++){
                            if(element.index[i].ref == tema){
                                var next = i + 1;
                                final = element.index[next].ref;

                            }       
                        }
                    return final;
                })
    console.log(siguiente) //returns undefined 

    res.render("cursos/" + tema + page, {curso: foundCourse, page: page, tema: tema});
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hola gracias por responderme, me sigue dando undefined. Per en cambio si le meto console.log() dentro del if statement me sale el resultado que quiero!

Comment: Perfecto, al final si que me ha funcionado asignando la variable fuera del loop. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda y un saludoo!!